# ListFieldIterator for Edit forms

Tags: 2013

I've created New item form with ListFieldIterator but now I need to build one in EDIT and Display Mode.

Can you guide me how to achieve it for Edit mode? Simply changing `ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit` doesn't work.